# Handle Event inside bound ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm struggling to solve this problem, i'm trying to handle the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown & MouseEnter & MouseLeave event inside my bound ListBox. Currently learning WPF.

The Image is inside my ListBox with other Controls here's a Picture for clarification.

**My Problem** is the two **Image Controls are not known in Code behind** because they are inside a DataTemplate and thats why i cant handle them.

[image]

Heres my Xaml Code:

```
<ListBox Name="ListBoxDownload" Height="414" Width="729" Canvas.Left="-3" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas Height="89" >
                <Canvas Height="86" Width="11" Background="#FFC33232" Canvas.Left="-2"/>
                <ProgressBar Width="694" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="76" Height="10" Value="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Maximum="{Binding Maximum}" Minimum="0"/>
                <Label Foreground="White" FontFamily="/SpotWatch;component/Resources/Fonts/#Montserrat Light" FontSize="18" Content="{Binding Name}" Canvas.Left="14" Canvas.Top="-4"/>
                <Label Foreground="#FFC3BDBD" FontFamily="/SpotWatch;component/Resources/Fonts/#Montserrat Ultra Light" FontSize="14" Content="{Binding Artist}" Canvas.Left="14" Canvas.Top="25"/>
                <Label Foreground="#FF8D8D8D" FontFamily="/SpotWatch;component/Resources/Fonts/#Montserrat Ultra Light" FontSize="12" Content="{Binding Status}" Canvas.Left="14" Canvas.Top="50"/>
                <Image Name="ImageDeleteSong" Source="/Resources/Images/SpotWatch.Delete.png" Canvas.Left="675" Canvas.Top="6" Width="17" Height="19" MouseEnter="ImageDeleteSong_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="ImageDeleteSong_MouseLeave" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ImageDeleteSong_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
                <Image Name="ImageRemoveSong" Source="/Resources/Images/SpotWatch.Remove.png" Canvas.Left="697" Canvas.Top="6" Width="17" Height="19" MouseEnter="ImageRemoveSong_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="ImageRemoveSong_MouseLeave" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ImageRemoveSong_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: You haven't described the problem at all

Comment: What problem? Tell us.

Comment: Sorry if i didnt described it well, see the Edit

Answer (score 0):

The images do not need to be known in code behind, if you hook up the events you get the image control passed as the first argument. You just need to cast it.

Alternatively wrap the images in a button, bind the `Command` and pass something via the `CommandParameter` binding as needed. (Usually i avoid events and bind commands on view-models instead.)

---

Why do you need to access the images anyway? That's not something you should need to do. If you need to modify them you should bind the respective properties and then modify your bound data instead.

---

Given what you said in the comments, this is what i would do:

```
public SomeViewModel()
{
    _deleteUser = new DelegateCommand(user =>
        Users.Remove((Person)user)
    );
}

private readonly ObservableCollection<Person> _Users;
public ObservableCollection<Person> Users { get { return _Users; } }

private readonly DelegateCommand _deleteUser;
public DelegateCommand DeleteUser { get { return _deleteUser; } }
```

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <!-- Some content here -->
                <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl},
                                        Path=DataContext.DeleteUser}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}">Remove</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Key points:

1. Delete command at level of list.
2. Button binds to it via `RelativeSource`
3. Passes current item (`{Binding}`) as parameter.
4. Command casts parameter and removes it from list.

(`DelegateCommand` is a simple delegate based implementation of `ICommand`, you can find implementation examples on the web.)

Comment: i cant clarify my problem more than that.

Comment: in my listBox is more than just 1 item so im trying to remove/delete them by clicking on the Icon wich is the Image Control

Comment: @iNCEPTiON_: As noted i would use a button with a `Command` for that. Also that's not an action for the item but rather the view-model one level up.

Comment: @iNCEPTiON_: Also this is the question you should have asked in the first place: **i'm trying to remove/delete them by clicking on the Icon**

Comment: @iNCEPTiON_: Added example.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed Answer ! i would upvote you if i could. I will try your Solution, But since this is a small project and i didnt want to use MVVM so i need to use it anyway since there is no other solution

Comment: @iNCEPTiON_: You could use the events as described as well, and MVVM does not require much overhead anyway.

Comment: i need to dive in into MVVM anyway :) if i use the events could i get the selected Item with ListBox.SelectedIndex for removing from List or is it more complicated?

Comment: @iNCEPTiON_ `SelectedIndex` would require that the selection happened prior to the event, if that is the case it should work. Probably a lot more messy than MVVM though.